# How to send custom emojis with bot - discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

I have been trying to send custom emojis with my bot, but instead of showing the emoji it just says "None". I tried other ways but none worked.. I am a beginner so sorry if it's a dumb mistake.

The code:

```
@client.command()
async def sendemoji(ctx):
    emoji = client.get_emoji(802812170672275467)
    await ctx.send(f'{emoji}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom emotes are represented internally in the following format:
<:name:id>
Where the name is the name of the custom emote, and the ID is the id of the custom emote.

You can quickly obtain the <:name:id> format by putting a backslash in front of the custom emoji when you put it in your client.
Example: :python3: would give you the <:name:id> format.

Animated emojis are the same as above but have an a before the name- ie: <a:name:id>

Example:

```py
await ctx.send('Python 3 emoji: <:python3:232720527448342530> !')
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if the emoji is called xyz,
you do '<:xyz:id>'

If xyz is an animated emoji,
you do '<a:xyz:id>'

Also, make sure that the bot is in the server where this emoji is from.
I hope this is helpful

Comment: I tried this but it just says ":emoji:" instead of sending the actual emoji.

Comment: add me on discord StatTrakDiamondSword#3000 i'll try to help there